# JSON parse for TFL Open Data

Tags: java, android, json, json-api

Hello everyone I'm trying to parse a JSON file from this [LINK](https://api.tfl.gov.uk/journey/journeyresults/1000266/to/1000013).

The returned JSON is as follows-

[image]

I need to loop through all the instances of **`journeys`** first, then I have to loop through **`legs`** for each **`journeys`** to get the **`detailed`** instruction. As you can see each **`legs`** consists of **`instruction`** in parts which returns a **`string`**, my ultimate goal is to combine these **`string`** for each journeys and display them as a **`TextView`**. So for the above JSON the end goal is to display -

> **Jubilee line towards Stratford, or North Greenwich**
>
> **Northern line towards Edgware, or High Barnet**

Till now I've been trying to navigate through this **`JSON`** without any luck.

Here is the code I've been working on-

```
try {
       //object is the JSON file.
       JSONArray Journey = object.getJSONArray("journeys");
       if (Journey != null) {
        //Retrieving number of possible routes.
        for (int i=0;i<Journey.length();i++){
             Routes.add(Journey.getJSONObject(i));
        }
        //Retrieving number of possible legs for each route.
        if (!Routes.isEmpty()){
        for (int j = 0; j< Routes.size(); j++){
             Legs.add(j, Routes.get(j).getJSONArray("legs"));
        }
        //Trying to retrieve the detailed instruction here and failing.
        for(int k=0;k<Routes.get(k).getJSONArray("legs").length();k++){
            instructionDetail.add(k,Legs.get(k).getJSONObject(k).getJSONObject("instruction"));
          
        }
     }
 }

} catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
              }
```

I believe my approach is wrong and I didn't get the loop right.. Suggestions to parse and navigate and any other approach will be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

UPDATE:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONArray journeys = new JSONObject("");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < journeys.length() ; i++) { // Traverse journeys
            JSONObject journey = journeys.getJSONObject(i); // get journeys(i) -> journey
            if(journey.has("legs")) { // if journey has "legs" key
                JSONArray legs = journey.getJSONArray("legs"); // get the legs array from journey object
                for(int j = 0 ; j < legs.length() ; j++) { // Traverse legs
                    JSONObject leg = legs.getJSONObject(j); // get legs(j) -> leg
                    if(leg.has("instruction")) { // if leg has "instruction" key in it 
                        JSONObject instruction = leg.getJSONObject("instruction"); // get instruction jsonObject
                        String detailed = instruction.optString("detailed", "Fallback detailed"); // get detailed string in instruction object
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Update:

```
private static class Detail {
        String journeyType;
        String legType;
        String instructionType;
        String detail;

        public Detail(String journeyType, String legType, String instructionType, String detail) {
            this.journeyType = journeyType;
            this.legType = legType;
            this.instructionType = instructionType;
            this.detail = detail;
        }
    }
```

...
...

```
List<Detail> detailList = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONArray journeys = new JSONObject("");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < journeys.length() ; i++) { // Traverse journeys
            JSONObject journey = journeys.getJSONObject(i); // get journeys(i) -> journey
            if(journey.has("legs")) { // if journey has "legs" key
                JSONArray legs = journey.getJSONArray("legs"); // get the legs array from journey object
                for(int j = 0 ; j < legs.length() ; j++) { // Traverse legs
                    JSONObject leg = legs.getJSONObject(j); // get legs(j) -> leg
                    if(leg.has("instruction")) { // if leg has "instruction" key in it
                        JSONObject instruction = leg.getJSONObject("instruction"); // get instruction jsonObject
                        String journeyType = journey.getString("$type");
                        String legType = leg.getString("$type");
                        String instructionType = instruction.getString("$type");
                        String detailed = instruction.getString("detailed"); // get detailed string in instruction object
                        detailList.add(new Detail(journeyType, legType, instructionType, detailed));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for(Detail detail : detailList) {
            TextView textView = new TextView([yourContext]);
            textView.setText(detail.detail);
            yourContentViewGroup.addView(textView);
            // or you can use View.inflate(context, layoutRes, yourContentViewGroup) and design a layout to show other detail instance values
        }
```

Comment: Sorry i missed the instruction object, i edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain the code for me a little bit please? I'm a novice!

Comment: Yes, basicly after you get the journey array, you traverse it and check every json object if it has "legs" in it. Then you get the legs array and traverse it in another loop and check if it has an "instruction in it. When you find it you get the instruction object and get the detailed string. optString is similar as getString except you can give a fallback to it.

Comment: The loop structure is excellent but it doesn't achieve what I have intended. as per the update above the `instruction` object is replaced every time the last loop is completed. My intention was as follows:

**First, list possible journeys returned by the API call.**
**Second, display the combined instruction for each journey.**

So for journey `0`:

**Jubilee line towards Stratford, or North Greenwich**
**Northern line towards Edgware, or High Barnet**

And so on..

Comment: Yea I thought you put the detailed strings into array and then create a ui corresponding to it. Since it is a nested loop, you can also access upper level objects like instruction information of that detail or leg information or so on. Here's an update for modeling your detail and create a simple ui for it.

Comment: Oh and one more thing, the best practice would be to create the detailList asynchronously like where you get your result from the request, then inflate the view and set textviews in ui. And better to use a listview or recyclerview than to inflate the views to a container viewgroup.